# unable to append data using java-script given by explode function

Tags: javascript, php

i am trying to read input from a file using explode function.  when i am passing the values to a java-script variable and the appending a div tag with elements of the array i get undefined as out.

```html
<?php

$strings = file_get_contents('questions.txt');
$new_string = explode('<hr>', $strings);
$count = count($new_string);
echo $count;

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="questions">
 
</div>
<div id ="options">
 
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = document.getElementById("questions");
var string = <?php echo json_encode($new_string); ?>;

var mi = document.createElement("input");
mi.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
mi.setAttribute('name','options');
mi.setAttribute('value', 'default');
for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    
    x.innerHTML = string[i]+ "<br>"+"<br>";
    for(var j=0; j<4;j++){
     x.innerHTML += new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(mi); 
     x.innerHTML+= string[i+j]+"<br>";
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

contents from question.txt:
1.Principle: When a person who has made a promise to another perso
n to do something does not fulfill his promise, the other person beco
mes entitled to receive, from the person who did not fulfill his promi
se, compensation in the form of money.
Facts: ‘X’ made a promise to ‘Y’ to repair his car engine. ‘Y’ made the
payment for repair. After the repair, ‘Y’ went for a drive in the same c
ar. While driving the car, ‘Y’ met with an accident due to bursting of a
tyre.

---

1. ‘X’ will not be entitled to receive compensation.

---

2. ‘Y’ will not be entitled to receive compensation from ‘X’.

---

3. ‘Y’ will be entitled to receive compensation from ‘X’ in the form of
money.

---

4. ‘X’ will be entitled to receive compensation from ‘Y’ in the form of
money.

---

Comment: Could you provide the contents of `questions.txt`?

Comment: What does `console.log(string)` show?

Comment: You sure `questions.txt` contains `<hr>` tags. Seems more appropriate for a `questions.html` file...

Comment: Not your problem but `+ "<br>"+"<br>";` would be easier to read/code/debug as `+ "<br><br>";`

Answer (score 0):

console.log(string) gives the following output
["1.Principle: When a person who has made a promise …’ met with an accident due to bursting of a↵tyre.", "↵1. ‘X’ will not be entitled to receive compensation.", "↵2. ‘Y’ will not be entitled to receive compensation from ‘X’.", "↵3. ‘Y’ will be entitled to receive compensation from ‘X’ in the form of↵money.", "↵4. ‘X’ will be entitled to receive compensation from ‘Y’ in the form of↵money.", "↵↵2.Principle: Where one of the parties to a contr…nt from the patient. The patient refused t↵o pay.", "↵1. The contract is enforceable against the doctor.", "↵2. The contract is not enforceable as doctor was in dominating posit↵ion.", "↵3. The contract is enforceable against the patient by the doctor.", "↵4. The contract is not enforceable without the consent of the patien↵t.", "↵↵3.Principle: Penal laws provide that whoever vol…rested the man and produced him↵before the Court.", "↵1. Court will punish the man for rape.", "↵2. Court will not punish the police officer.", "↵3. Court will punish the police officer.", "↵4. Court will not punish the man for rape.", "↵↵4.Principle: Whoever takes away with him any min…umbai wit↵hout informing the parents of the girl.", "↵1. ‘A’ committed an offence against the girl as well as her parents.", "↵2. ‘A’ committed an offence against the girl.", "↵3. ‘A’ committed no offence against the parents of the girl.", "↵4. ‘A’ committed no offence against the girl as well as her parents.", "↵↵↵GENERAL KNOWLEDGE↵↵5.The Hubble telescope of NASA is located in", "↵1. Iceland", "↵2. Canada", "↵3. Space", "↵4. NASA headquarters", "↵↵6.The first Commercial Court and Commercial Disputes Resolution Ce↵ntre was inaugurated at", "↵1. Mumbai, Maharastra", "↵2. Ahmedabad, Gujarat", "↵3. Visakapatinam, Andhra Pradesh", "↵4. Raipur, Chattisgarh", "↵↵7.Among the following who was crowned as ‘Miss Supernational’ duri↵ng 2016?", "↵1. Alia Bhat", "↵2. Aishwarya Rai", "↵3. Shilpa Shetty", "↵4. Srinidhi Shetty", "↵↵8.How many billionaires India has lost since demonetization on Novem↵ber 8, 2016?", "↵1. Eight", "↵2. Two", "↵3. Eleven", "↵4. Eighteen", ""]